# I am trying to use material ui Select in Formik but getting warning about findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

Is there a way to use the Material UI select in Formik without getting this findDOMNode warning message?
I have a simple ReactJs App. I have not posted the whole code but just the section where I am facing this issue.
Formik version is : 2.1.5.
Please check the warning message here : [findDOMNode warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03klV.png)

```
import {
  Grid,
  Typography,
  TextField,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
  FormHelperText,
} from "@material-ui/core";
 import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";

const data = {hours : ''}
     
<Formik
 initialValues={data}
 >
    <Form>
     <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
         <Typography variant="subtitle2">TC1 CONFIGURATION</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item>
            <FormControl>
              <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
                Hours
              </InputLabel>
              <Field
                name="hours"
                type="select"
                as={Select}
              >
                <MenuItem value={60}>01</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={120}>02</MenuItem>
              </Field>
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Form>
<Formik/>
```